# How to access ASP .NET MVC URL?

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

I am doing code by watching Mosh ASP .Net tutorial. But I stack on a thing. My routing url is not working but query string is working.

Here is my code:

**routing code**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "MovieByReleaseDate",
                "movie/released/{year}/{month}",
                new {controller = "Movie", action = "ByReleaseDate" }
                );
```

**action code**

```
public ActionResult ByReleaseDate(int year, int month)
        {
            return Content(year+"/"+month);
        }
```

but link is not working. screenshot added
*http://localhost:49941/Movie/ByReleaseDate/2015/12*

[but link is not working. screenshot added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp5Jw.png)

working with query
[working this only screenshot added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQDWS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you not defining a proper routing, you won't accomplish your goal.
Looks like you need a better understanding on routing.

Please refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

You are not following the convention in those cases where you want to use explicit routing instead of using the query string.

Try adding the default values into the route definition.

new {controller = "Movie", action = "ByReleaseDate" ,year=0, month=0 }

Basically when you defining routings you need to define the way that you will receive the information.

new {controller = "Movie", action = "ByReleaseDate" }
Will allow you to route below patterns

- {controller}/{action}
- {controller}/{action}? "query string"

new {controller = "Movie", action = "ByReleaseDate",year=0 }
Will allow you to route below patterns

- {controller}/{action}/year
- {controller}/{action}? "query string"
- {controller}/{action}/year? "query string"

Answer (score 0):

you should edit your routing code like this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "MovieByReleaseDate",
            "movie/released/{year}/{month}",
            new {controller = "Movie", action = "ByReleaseDate", year = 0 , month = 0 }
            );
```

and in URL you can use something like this

http://localhost:44360/movie/released/2021/1

--notice your port is different